# How to find deadlock, timeout and memory issues using JMeter?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to performance testing. I have a task on measuring the web application performance. I need to find out which modules/calls are causing deadlock, timeout and memory issues.

Q1. How can I use JMeter to find out deadlock, memory and timeout issues? If I do the following steps, it is the right way to trace those issues?

1. create a test plan in JMeter, which contains multiple Thread Group.
2. In each thread group, it contains multiple HTTP requests and 200 or
   more users plus infinite loop.
3. Monitor JMeter results and SQL
   profiler for deadlock.

Q2. JMeter is the right tool for tracking those issues? Or, should I use browser based performance testing tool such as LoadNinja, LoadView?

Thanks
Bonnie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Q1 JMeter per se doesn't provide any toolchain to detect deadlock and memory issues, the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)) provides possibility to set the timeouts, if the value is blank - it will default to operating system timeout or web server timeout, whatever comes the first

   [image]

   If you conduct some form of [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_(software)), i.e. start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load at some point you will see that response time starts growing and number of requests per second starts decreasing. So it's the point of maximum system performance and after that the performance will be degrading.

   To monitor application under test memory you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/), it will allow you to state whether the lack of RAM is the cause of the performance issue
   With regards to deadlocks, it should result in HTTP Request sampler failure (or timeout), JMeter won't give you the underlying reason, but it will give you the timestamp and you should be able to check what happened with your application/database at that moment.
2. Q2 [well-behaved JMeter test must produce the same network footprint as a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), if your test plan is good enough the system under test shouldn't be able to distinguish whether it's being hit by JMeter or by a real user using the real browser. JMeter will not give you client-side performance metrics like page rendering time or JavaScript execution time as:

   > [JMeter is not a browser](https://jmeter.apache.org/), it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).